# Error when creating dynamic two dimensional array in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to increase the x value of the 2 dimensional array but I keep receiving this error.

```
'ReDim' can only change the rightmost dimension
```

I need to do this while maintaining the data of the array. Here is my code.

```
            Dim x As Integer = 0
            Dim y As Integer = 0
            While reader.Read()
                ReDim Preserve catagoryInfo(x, 2)
                catagoryInfo(x, y) = reader.GetString(0)
                y += 1
                catagoryInfo(x, y) = reader.GetString(1)
                x += 1
                y = 0
            End While
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a multidimensional array, you can change only the last dimension when you use Preserve. If you attempt to change any of the other dimensions, a run-time error occurs. 
A part from this your code is really suboptimal because you are planning to Redim you array at every loop. Redimming with preserve is worse because not only the runtime allocates a new array but it should also copy from the old array to the new array.

In your case is better to declare a simple class like this

```
Public Class CategoryInfo
    Public info1 As String
    Public info2 As String
End Class
```

then use a List(Of CategoryInfo)

```
Dim infos as List(Of CategoryInfo) = new List(Of CategoryInfo)()
While reader.Read()
    Dim nf As CategoryInfo = new CategoryInfo() 
    nf.info1 = reader.GetString(0)
    nf.info2 = reader.GetString(1)
    infos.Add(nf)
    ' if you like the all-in-one-line coding style you could also write the above in this way
    ' infos.Add(New CategoryInfo With {.info1=reader.GetString(0), .info2=reader.GetString(1)} )
End While
```

Now, if you really need to have your data inside a string array you could write

```
Dim categoryInfo(infos.Count, 2) as String
for x = 0 to infos.Count -1
    categoryInfo(x,0) = infos(x).info1
    categoryInfo(x,1) = infos(x).info2
next
```

this is still not very optimal because you loop two times on your data but, at least, it will get your data as you want.

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a shot. Still familiarizing myself with the data flow in vb.net. Would it be fine to pass a list through a function or should I even bother converting it to an array?

Comment: Well, arrays have their value. They are very fast to get data from when you know the index. But I advise you to familiarize with Lists and other collections available in the Framework (Dictionary, Hashtable, etc). Of course you could pass a List(Of yourType) to every function or sub you like.

Comment: great! works perfectly. sent the list to the function and it works perfectly. I'd upvote it if i could :)

Comment: Glad to be of help. Remember to accept the answer when the site will allow you

Comment: +1. The advice to use List s of objects rather than 2D arrays is life-transforming